# Proper way to create a Makefile for a standard C++ project

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, meson-build

So, here's the thing. I have the below files and folders residing in my directory:

```
src/ obj/ include/ bin/  Makefile
```

As per the usual, in my `src/` directory I have my **.cpp** files and in my `include/` directory I have my **.hpp** files. There is no other sub-directory within any of these -- so, for all intensive purposes, this is a fairly *simple* project.

My question is simple. What is the best way to create the Makefile in such a case? More specifically, what is a good way of doing so? Previously I had a Makefile, but it did not recompile the needed files when I change something in a .hpp header only. So I did some research and I think the way to go about this is via automatic *dependencies*. I could be wrong, so bear with me.

Below is a sample of an unfinished (non-functioning) Makefile, thus far. Also, if you know how to properly set up a **meson** and **ninja** build system for such an example, that would be interesting too. Obviously, if there need be more context, I'd provide the needed files for a minimum-working example.

I know there are a lot of information about things like that, but for some reason, they either are fairly very complicated (for complicated projects) or extremely simple.

Any tips about how to set such files up would be very, very appreciated!

```
MAKE = make -j 8

# Define compiler.
CXX = g++
#CXX = mpicxx

# Program executable.
EXE = TEST

# Source files directory.
SRC_DIR := src
# Object files directory.
OBJ_DIR := obj
# Binary directory.
BIN_DIR := bin
# Dependency directory.
DEP_DIR := Dependencies

# Extract source files.
SRC := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
# Specify object files.
OBJ := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(SRC))   
# Dependency files.
DEP := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)%.cpp,$(DEP_DIR)%.d,$(SRC))

# Compiler debug flags.
#CXX_DBGFLAGS = -g -Wall -Werror

# Compiler standard flags.
CXX_STDFLAGS = -std=c++17

# Compiler Open MP flags.
#CXX_OMP = -fopenmp

# Compiler optimization flags.
#CXX_OPTFLAGS = -O2

# Compiler include files.
INCLUDE = -Iinclude

# Linear-algebra flags.
#LAPACK_FLAGS = -llapack -lblas

# Compiler flags.
CXX_FLAGS = $(CXX_OPTFLAGS) $(CXX_STDFLAGS) $(CXX_OMP) $(CXX_DBGFLAGS) $(INCLUDE)

# Linker flags.
#LDFLAGS = $(CXX_OPTFLAGS) $(LAPACK_FLAGS) $(OMP_FLAGS) 

# Linker libraries to link.
LDLIBS := 

# Linked.
LD := $(CXX)

# Dependency flags.
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(DEP_DIR)/$*.d

# Target executable.
TARGET := $(BIN_DIR)/$(EXE)

# Preprocessor flags.
CPPFLAGS =

# Precompiled steps.
PRECOMPILE =

# Post-compiled steps.
POSTCOMPILE = 

# Link object files to binary.
LINK.o = $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

# Compile commands.
COMPILE.cc = $(CXX) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -c -o $@


.PHONY: all 
default: all

all: 
    $(BIN_DIR)/$(EXE)


$(BIN_DIR)/$(EXE): $(OBJ) 
    $(LINK.o) $^

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(DEP_DIR)/%.d 
    $(PRECOMPILE) 
    $(COMPILE.cc) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)


.PRECIOUS: $(DEP_DIR)/%.d
    
$(DEP_DIR)/%.d: ;

-include $(DEP)
```

Comment: I've found [this setup](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/08/26/makefile-c-projects/) fairly useful. You don't need to include every gadget listed (I don't actually use the automatic detection of source files and prefer to explicitly enumerate them) but it can handle folders and dependencies fairly nicely.

Comment: Right off the bat, this line: `MAKE = make -j8` is not right.  You should never set the `MAKE` variable in a makefile (or at least, only in very specific, very unusual circumstances).  Next, it's uncommon to run the program you built in the `all` target.  You should not use `.PRECIOUS`.  Lastly, SO is not a place where people write code, it's a place where people with specific problems with code they're trying to get working can ask for help about those problems.  So you say the above makefile is "non-functioning".  If you describe what doesn't function about it we can help you fix it.

Comment: Also, a nit: it's not _for all intensive purposes_.  It's _for all intents and purposes_ :).

Comment: It really is better to start with a simple, crude makefile that works, then work up to a sophisticated and efficient one, rather than ask for help fixing an advanced makefile that doesn't work. Make has a learning curve, and you can't maintain a makefile you don't understand. Automatic dependency handling, in particular, is an advanced technique, not the first thing to learn.